# How do you call a parameter?

Tags: javascript

I've learned how to call variables in JavaScript:
*(variableName represents your variable name)*

```
variableName;
```

> After declaring a variable or function with the `var` keyword, you can call it at any time by using its name.

So, how must one call a parameter in JavaScript?

Will it be like this?

```
function sampleFunction(foo) {
  foo; // Parameter invoking?
}
```

Or should I just use what I know and do this?

```
function sampleFunction(foo) {
  // Assigning the "foo" parameter to "something" and then attempting to call it
  something = foo;
  something;
}
```

## Need more info?

In the previous question "How do you do something in a parameter", I meant "How do you call a paramater?".
That question was about one of the planned features of my project Xi, `event()`.
The command had a parameter named `toDo` – but for now it'll be named `a`.

```
// These commands are NOT real.
function event(a) {
  when(a) {
    a;
  }
}
```

But, the problem is that I don't actually know how to call `a`.

- `a()` should probably not be used because the program may throw an error because the argument passed onto `a` is not a function.
- Using assignment may be discouraged because it might just to the same thing.
- Either I can refer to the variable or try something different.

Comment: What do you mean by _"call"_? Typically, you only _call_ functions. As for your examples, the first one is appropriate. The second one is redundant

Comment: "Invoke" and "call" are not the ideal verbs for non-function variables or parameters.  "Reference" makes more sense.  In your last function, the right way to say what you're doing on the first line is "assigning" the value of parameter foo to an (undeclared) local variable.  The lines where you just reference a symbol but do nothing with it is valid but superfluous. (the state of your program before and after the execution of that line is unchanged).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Since it looks like JavaScript, I'm assuming you can do this:

```js
function sampleFunction(foo) {
    foo(); // CALL the parameter just like you would say `sampleFunction()`
}

sampleFunction(function () {
    console.log("Hello World!");
});
```

Comment: i don't see how `foo()` does anything :/

Comment: actually yeah i kinda get it, thx

Answer (score -1):

I think you're using javascript terminology in a wrong way. Invoke means 'to execute' and it's the same as calling a function. Variable stores values - objects or primitives. You can assign a function to a variable and then call it, like that:

```
function myFunction(a, b) {
  return a * b;
}
var valueReturnedbyFunction = myFunction(10, 2); 

console.log(valueReturnedbyFunction );
```

So function is a separate block of code which does something and usually returns a value. But you don't invoke variables.

Comment: I think this is not what he asked. his question is how he can use variables or access a variable in a function.

Comment: I'm just pointing out some problems with used terms. You don't invoke variables. You can assign a function to a variable and call it. The  question is unclear - that's certain for me. I'm thinking that what he means is - if it's neccessary to convert 'parameter' to variable before using it inside the function. If so - the question is no.